# How can I add an attribute to the root

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way I can add the `StartDate` and `EndDate` variables to the Report node? I tried to add `select @StartDate as 'StartDate',@EndDate as 'StartDate'` after the  `ROOT('Report')` but that returns a different result.

Looking for something like this?

```
<Report>
<StartDate>03/01/2022</StartDate>
<EndDate>03/30/2022</EndDate>
  <Member>
    <UserActivityLogID>179</UserActivityLogID>
    <LogDate>03/10/2022</LogDate>
  </Member>
  <Member>
    <UserActivityLogID>180</UserActivityLogID>
    <LogDate>03/10/2022</LogDate>
  </Member>
</Report>
```

sp

```
 IF @StartDate IS NULL 
        BEGIN
            SET @StartDate = DateAdd(dd, -90, GetDate())
        END
    IF @EndDate IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @EndDate = GetDate()
        END
    BEGIN
        SELECT [UserActivityLogID]
              ,LogDate =Convert(varchar(10),[LogDate],101)
          and LogDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
          FROM [UserActivityLog]
          order by LogDate desc
        FOR XML PATH('Member'),
        ROOT('Report')
    END
```

Comment: If you want to add them to `Report` what is `Member` there for? It has no contents

Comment: `Member` is the dataset being return within the data range. If there is no content within the date range then members will be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a best guess, with no meaningful sample data nor expected results, what you want is:

```sql
SELECT UserActivityLogID AS [Member/UserActivityLogID],
       @StartDate AS [@StartDate],
       @EndDate AS [@EndDate]
FROM dbo.YourTable --You didn't even have a from in your query
WHERE --This was also missing
      LogDate >= @StartDAte
  AND LogDAte <= @EndDate
FOR XML PATH ('Report');
```

Comment: What if I wanted to keep the  `FOR XML PATH('Member'),`?

Comment: @Jefferson , as I said, you gave no sample data or expected results. I can't answer any more than  I have. You need to take the time to understand the above and then change it to your need